# How does a view know which layout to use? Where is the default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, razor

In default mvc app. There are Layout and content pages, You know (_Layout, Home, Contact, etc.)

And content pages do not contain layout refrence as this:

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

In content pages this code is missing. 
But they works. How does it do this without layout refrence?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because your `_ViewStart.cshtml` contains a reference to the default layout that will be used when a specific one is not stated on the view.

When you want to change the layout for a single view, you would include a `Layout = "...";` to that view.

Comment: This mean, If I dont define a layout, use default?

Comment: Its convention over configuration.

Answer (score 5):

If you want folder specific layouts i.e. (Home, Account, Product etc), you can put _ViewStart.cshtml in that folder & point out whichever layout tobe used in that file & it will override the root level layout.

Find ScottGu's blogs for more details on layouts & sections [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx) & [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)